# Do I need a parameter in this function?

Tags: javascript

[image]
In [this homework assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEPZY.png), I'm having issues with this part of the problem.

```
window.onload=setup;

function setup()
{
   var questions = document.querySelectorAll('ol  li');
   for (var i= 0; i < questions.length ; i++)
   {
      questions[i].id = i + "phrases";
      questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish;
      //questions[i].onmouseup = showFrench;
      questions[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
   }
}
function showEnglish()
{
   var phraseNumber = parseInt(question[i].id)
   document.getElementById(phraseNumber).innerHTML = english[phraseNumber];
   english[phraseNumber].style.font = "italic";
   english[phraseNumber].style.Color = "rgb(191,22,31)";
}
```

a) Using the id property of the list item experiencing the mousedown event, extract the index number with the the parseInt() function and store that value in the phraseNumber variable.

I get an error, saying questions is not defined in the showenglish().
Am I supposed to be referencing another object?

Comment: please add your code **in text** form to the question.

Comment: `questions` would be scoped to your setUp function and wouldn't be available outside it. when you're setting showEnglish as a callback function for mousedown events, it won't have access to your `questions` variable or your for loop's `i` variable.

Comment: As an aside, `style.Color` is not going to do much, since it should be `style.color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the question as a parameter:

```
for(i=0;i<question.length;i++){
let a=i;//important for scoping
question[a].onmousedown=function(){
   showEnglish(question[a]);
}
}

function showEnglish(question){
document.getElementById(question.id).style.font="italic";
...
}
```

(Note: this answer contains ES6. Do not use it in real productional environment. The let a=i; defines that a is kept for being used inside of the listener, while i will always be question.length, because the event is probably clicked after the loop occured...)

Alternatively, the event listener binds *this* as the clicked element:

```
question[i].addEventListener("click",showEnglish,false);

function showEnglish(){
document.getElementById(this.id).style.font="italic";
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mousedown` event is raised when the user presses the mouse button. Look at the [documentation for the `mousedown` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown).

Your event handler function will be passed an Event object, which has a `target` property, which is a reference to the element that the mouse clicked on.
You can access this inside your event handler function with `event.target`.

```
window.onload = setup;

function setup() {
  var questions = document.querySelectorAll('ol  li');

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i].id = i + "phrases";
    questions[i].onmousedown = showEnglish;
    //questions[i].onmouseup = showFrench;
    questions[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
}

function showEnglish(event) {
  var phraseNumber = parseInt(event.target.id);
  // etc
};
```